# Why is my ES6 string concatenation failing?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to concatenate a string with some value stored in a variable. It is failing due to Unexpected token error.

I tried using ES6 style of string concatenation

```
const MapWithASearchBox = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ width: '100vw',height: '100vh' }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
```

Here, the variable GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY holds the value, I am trying to use it through the variable.

I am getting this error:

```
/MapWithASearchBox.js: Unexpected token, expected ,
```

```
 13 | const MapWithASearchBox = compose(
  14 |   withProps({
> 15 |     googleMapURL=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
     |                                                                ^
  16 |     loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  17 |     containerElement: <div style={{ width: '100vw',height: '100vh' }} />,
  18 |     mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `` ` `` inside the template literal:

```
googleMapURL=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
//                                                       ^^                    ^^
```

The template literal will end at the second `` ` ``, i.e. JavaScript sees `` `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` `` as one literal, and tries to evaluate `${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}` as normal JavaScript code.

Maybe it's easier to see if we look at normal string literals:

```
"foo"      // ok
"foo"bar"  // not ok, interpreted as `"foo"` followed by `bar"`, syntax error
"foo\"bar" // ok because the second `"` is escaped, i.e. does not 
           // signify the end of the string literal
```

The same applies to any delimiter, including template literals.

But in your case the inner backticks are just wrong so you should remove them.